# Why does .collect() sometimes infer Vec but other times infers &Vec?

Tags: generics, rust, vector

I have the following code-snippets:

**1. get the n-th element of a Vec recursively**

```
fn helper<T: Clone>(n: usize, current_n: usize, current_xs: &Vec<T>, accumulator: Option<T>) -> Option<T> {
    if current_n > n {
        accumulator
    } else {
        let head = current_xs.get(0).cloned();
        let tail = current_xs.clone().into_iter().skip(1).collect();
        return helper(n, current_n + 1, &tail, head);
    }
}
```

**2. get the length of a Vec recursively**

```
fn helper<T: Clone>(current_xs: &Vec<T>, accumulator: usize) -> usize {
    if current_xs.is_empty() {
        accumulator
    } else {
        let tail = current_xs.clone().into_iter().skip(1).collect();
        return helper(tail, accumulator + 1)
    }
}
```

My Question is about that line:

```
let tail = current_xs.clone().into_iter().skip(1).collect();
```

In the first example the `tail` variable is of Type `Vec<T>` and in the second example the `tail` variable is of type `&Vec<?>`.

**Questions:**

- Why? Why returns the the exact line of code two different types?
- How can I return a `Vec<T>` in the second example?

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=65cf493e711a657d8433d7f1edfcfff0)

Comment: Side note: I know you're just doing this as an exercise but it's still useful to note that (and for future readers), it's more idiomatic to take a slice as an argument instead of an immutable reference to a `Vec`

Comment: What gives you the impression that these two variables have different types? The second example simply does not compile, and can be fixed by changing `tail` to `&tail` in the call to `helper()`.

Comment: @justinas lol... you are right, when I modify the helper call to `return  helper(&tail, accumulator + 1)` in IntelliJ the 'type' of tail changes to `Vec<T>`. But I still don't get it, why does the line after `let tail ...` has an effect on that line `let tail...`

Comment: @SvenMarnach IntelliJ says it. it resolve the types somehow.

Comment: @SleepyX667 can you please create a [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/) with a minimal example so that everyone is on the same page and observes the same things you do

Comment: @sshashank124 whats a playground link? Do I have to create a github repository?

Comment: @SleepyX667 You don't specify a type for `tail`, so its type needs to be inferred by the Rust compiler. The `collect()` method has a generic return type, so it's not useful for inferring the type – you could collect the iterator into any of several types of collections. Hence the conmpiler uses other information it has on `tail` to restrict its type – in this case the fact that it is passed as parameter to `helper()`, so it should have the type of that parameter.

Comment: @SleepyX667 https://play.rust-lang.org/

Comment: I recommend trying to _compile_ your code and looking closely at the error messages. In most cases, Rust's error messages are quite useful and give lots of pointers as to what's going on.

Comment: @SleepyX667 also I would recommend updating your question title to something more relevant to your question, such as "Collecting to a Vec vs &Vec" or something else that's descriptive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example, [`collect` can return anything that implements `FromIterator<Self::Item>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) (here `Self::Item` is `T`). So the compiler tries to guess the type of `tail` by looking at how it is used. When you call `helper (tail, …)`, the compiler guesses that `tail` should have the same type as the first argument to `helper`, aka `&Vec<U>` for some as yet unknown type `U`. However, `&Vec<U>` does *not* implement `FromIterator<T>`, so the compiler bails out at this point.

OTOH when you call `helper (&tail, …)`, the compiler guesses that `&tail` should have type `&Vec<U>` for some `U`, and therefore `tail` should have type `Vec<U>`. The compiler can then continue and determine that `U==T`, which gives the complete type of `tail` as `Vec<T>`.

---

As an aside, here is a more idiomatic implementation of your first `helper` that avoids unnecessary copies. Something similar can be done for the second one:

```
fn helper<T: Clone> (n: usize, current_n: usize, current_xs: &[T], accumulator: Option<&T>) -> Option<T> 
{
    if current_n > n {
        accumulator.cloned()
    } else {
        let head = current_xs.get (0);
        let tail = &current_xs[1..];
        return if tail.is_empty() { 
            None
        } else {
            helper (n, current_n + 1, tail, head)
        };
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    println!("Element 3: {:?}", helper (3, 0, &v, None));
    println!("Element 10: {:?}", helper (10, 0, &v, None));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=565703466392eb0cc169220ea3e67da5)

Comment: [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5264f0f8c52821b172777fe0338f956f) is a more idiomatic implementation

Comment: @Stargateur: I got: `error[E0658]: subslice patterns are unstable`, if I don't use nighly channel.

Comment: @SleepyX667 so use [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0a077970b6018b1453dd2fcb00cab665), the feature I used just get stabilized in rustc 1.42. This doesn't change much, the point of my code was to reduce the use of useless variable.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is:

**Example 1:** calls the recursive function with

```
return helper(n, current_n + 1, &tail, head); // &tail
```

**Example 2:** calls the recursive function with:

```
return  helper(tail, accumulator + 1) // tail
```

Changing `tail` to `&tail` everything works.
At the moment I can't exactly explain why, so i would wait to accept this as correct answer and hope someone else can completely answer it.

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=122552ae306d389c5975ebdf82332459)

Comment: "everything works", I can't wait you try a vector with something like 10000 element.